# Create lock using unix socket/port

Tags: shell-script, tcp, netcat, lock, port

Is there a way to hold a lock a unix port using netcat or some other command?

I want to do something like this:

```
set -e;
nc -lock 8000 &  # this needs to fail if another process holds the lock
wait;
my-proc  # start my process
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Abstract unix socket ([`man 7 unix`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)):

> - abstract: an abstract socket address is distinguished (from a
>           pathname socket) by the fact that sun_path[0] is a null byte
>           ('\0').  The socket's address in this namespace is given by the
>           additional bytes in sun_path that are covered by the specified
>           length of the address structure.  (Null bytes in the name have no
>           special significance.)  The name has no connection with filesystem
>           pathnames.
>     [...]

Its main interest here is that this socket doesn't stay around when the process which created it dies. Luckily `socat` provides an `ABSTRACT-LISTEN` method specifically for abstract sockets (avoiding having to handle `'\0'` in parameters and shell). Thus allowing to implement [this python method](https://www.aychedee.com/2012/05/26/interprocess-locking-without-using-lockfiles/) in shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

socat ABSTRACT-LISTEN:/myownapplock - >/dev/null &
socatpid=$!

sleep 2 # wait for socat to have executed and be listening or have failed
if pgrep -P $$ '^socat$'; then
    locked=yes
else
    locked=no
    echo >&2 'Lock failed.'
    exit 1
fi

my-proc

kill $socatpid # cleanup once my-proc is done
```

Running the same code a 2nd time will fail. I'm sure the `sleep 2` can be improved, but this code is still race-free (as long as socat takes less than 2 seconds to start). The abstract socket can be seen for example with `netstat -xlp|fgrep @/myownapplock`.